# Migration Data from legacy table to new mysql mysql with django ORM gives Error

Tags: mysql, django

I was migrating some legacy data from another MySQL database to a new one using Django ORM. The old application was created in Perl and MySQL.

But while migrating I keep getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: (1118, 'Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.')
```

I dropped the table and recreated with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED (which implies ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC) but still I am getting this error.

I couldn't find any working solution for fixing this. Has anyone else encountered such situations?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Both Databases(legacy and new) are MySQL

Comment: Sorry I meant what _storage engine_ of MySQL are you using.

Comment: Both Using InnoDB. I didn't make a selection in the new schema. I guess django ORM itself created tables using InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Row size too large (> 8126)](http://instantbadger.blogspot.fr/2013/01/mysql-row-size-too-large-when-saving.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was a straight forward solution